# Spring Data Rest Custom Controller With with content-Type:"text/plain"

Tags: java, content-type, spring-data-rest

I have been trying to write a custom functionality where a REST end point consumes a plain-text . Here is the piece of code:

```
@RepositoryRestController
@RequestMapping("/api/samples")
public class SampleController {

    @Autowired
    SampleRepository sampleRepository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT, consumes = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public void updateSample(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody String message ) {
        //do some custom logic here

        //sampleRepository.update(id);
    }

}
```

Spring Data rest throws a exception  `HttpStatus.UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE(415)`. However when I move the code to a separate Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/samples")
public class SampleController {

    @Autowired
    SampleRepository sampleRepository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT,consumes =MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public void updateSample(@PathVariable Long id,@RequestBody String message ) {
        //do some custom logic here

        //sampleRepository.update(id);
    }
}
```

This works Fine . Has Anyone faced similar issues, moving the code to a separate  method  resolves the issue(Work Around).

Any Suggestion on how to approach the problem would be great

Answer (score 0):

The only difference I see between your two code samples is the use of *@RepositoryRestController* in the first case versus *@RestController* in the second case.

When overriding endpoint that are auto-generated by Spring Data REST, such as *PUT /api/samples/{id}*, you should use *@RequestMapping* at the method level, for reasons exposed [here](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-535).

The official documentation does not explicitly forbidding class-level requestmapping, but the only [example](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#customizing-sdr.overriding-sdr-response-handlers) given it uses method-level requestmapping.

```
@RepositoryRestController
public class SampleController {

    @Autowired
    SampleRepository sampleRepository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/api/samples/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT, consumes = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public void updateSample(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody String message ) {
        //do some custom logic here

        //sampleRepository.update(id);
    }

}
```

If you use both *@RepositoryRestController* and *@RequestMapping* at the class level, you lose access to all endpoint handlers that Spring Data Rest usually generates. My guess is you're sending a request to */api/samples/{id}* without setting the content type to *text/plain*, so there is actually no endpoint that can handle your request, hence the error message.

A remark regarding the seconde code sample: *@ResponseBody* is implied by *@RestController*, so there is no need to annotate your method with it.